# style Vs contentContainerStyle in ScrollView?

Tags: react-native, scrollview

When I apply `{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}` to `style` prop, got following error,

> ScrollView child layout must be applied through the
>   contentContainerStyle prop

then applied same styling to `contentContainerStyle` and worked fine. I am unable to understand the basic difference between `style` and `contentContainerStyle` and when to use them.

I am assuming that when `ScrollView` is called, two `views` are called. `style` applicable to parent `View` and `contentContainerStyle` applicable to child `View`.

Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You're correct, think of it like this, ScrollView is a special kind of View, ScrollView has two parts:

1. Container (the grey box), it's the outside View, its height can't exceed 100% of the window height
2. Content (marked in blue) is the inner part, it can be higher than the window height, it's what's moving inside the container.

[image]

ScrollView `style` defines the outer container of the ScrollView, e.g its height and relations to siblings elements

ScrollView `contentContainerStyle` defines the inner container of it, e.g items alignments, padding, etc

Comment: Great answer! @tareq did you create the view hierarchy image or did you find it somewhere? Have been on the hunt for such images for ReactNative components for a while now.