# React native, scrollView is trimming the empty 'view' components(having background color as well)

Tags: react-native, scrollview

New to react native,  I have a view component with flex direction as row, now it is nested with two view components with background colours pink and blue respectively. It renders as expected.
[without Scrollview image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3czcV.jpg)

```
<View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'row'}}>
    <View style ={{flex:0.3, backgroundColor: 'pink'}}>
    </View>
    <View style ={{flex:0.7, backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>
    </View>
</View>
```

Now if i wrap above code inside scrollView then nothing is being rendered on screen. It is trimming the empty view components.I want scrollview also should render the empty view components with background colours.
[with scrollview image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfVHj.jpg)

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
    <ScrollView style={{flex:1}}>
        //above code here
    </ScrollView>
</View>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change ScrollView style prop to contentContainerStyle like this:

```
 <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flex:1}}>
```

check this link:
[style vs contentContainerStyle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52892304/style-vs-contentcontainerstyle-in-scrollview)

Comment: it works, but can you explain me a little what's happening ??

Comment: check the above link to know more about the difference between styles and contentContainerStyle in ScrollView

Comment: Thanks for the link, if i make contentContainerStyle to flex:1 then scrolling is not working.