# Problem positioning element to the bottom

Tags: react-native, native-base

I'm using native base as my app template and I've been trying to position two button elements above the footer using only flex. [Here is how the buttons are positioned currently.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ActAb.jpg)

I tried doing justifyContent: flex-end / space-between but the buttons remains far away from the footer.

```
 <Container>
        <Header>
          <MainHeader />
        </Header>
        <Content>
            <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}} >
                <View style={{  borderBottomColor: 'black', borderBottomWidth: 1, height: 50 }}>
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'center' }}>
                            <Text>Name</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'center' }}>
                            <Text>Sales</Text>
                        </View> 
                        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'center' }}>
                            <Text>Commission</Text>
                        </View> 
                        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'center' }}>
                            <Text>Payout</Text>
                        </View> 
                        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'center' }}>
                            <Text>Profit</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
                {this.renderRow()}
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'space-between' }} >
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignSelf: 'stretch', height: 50, justifyContent: 'space-between' }} >
                        <View style={{flex:1, alignSelf: 'center'}}>
                            <Button onPress={() => this.share(this.state.response)} title="Share"></Button>
                        </View>
                        <View style={{flex:1, alignSelf: 'center'}}>
                            <Button onPress={() => this.share(this.state.response)} title="Share"></Button>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        </Content>
        <Footer>
          <MainFooter />
        </Footer>
      </Container>
```

I want the share buttons to be at the bottom of the page above the footer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is basically because everything is inside `content` which is basically a scrollview. You can't send something to the end of scrollview as it is parent.

You can access the prop of `contentContainerStyle` of content from native base and then give it style of justifyConent & alignItens -> flex-end.

I hope it'll work.

[This will help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52892304/style-vs-contentcontainerstyle-in-scrollview)